# What is a good training dataset for face recognition?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on recognising a single person out of a set of about 20 individuals. Currently, the software detects faces, does low-pass filtering to reduce false positives, and records the **cropped** faces to a folder.

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) documentation on cascade classifier training is great. However, it simply can't address the specifics of face recognition.

---

### Negative images

> Negative samples are taken from arbitrary images. These images must
>   not contain detected objects.
>
> ... But each image should be (but not nessesarily) larger then a
>   training window size
>
> ...placing [the positive sample] on arbitrary background

What are the best negative samples for face recognition?

- Other faces or just objects?
- Close to expected lightning and face orientation or random?
- How to determine number of samples (as samples need to be prepared by hand, if they are faces)?
- Larger than positive images or the same size?
- Or do I need many shots of the possible backgrounds?

---

### Positive images

> you may need only one positive sample for absolutely rigid object like
>   an OpenCV logo, but you definetely need hundreds and even thousands of
>   positive samples for faces. In the case of faces you should consider
>   all the race and age groups, emotions and perhaps beard styles.

The above extract is aimed at face **detection**, thus the large sample. I need to detect a single person. What would be a sane number of positive samples for this application?

Comment: please don't try to abuse cascades for [face recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html) as they can only deliver a "face? yes or no" answer.

Comment: As @berak says, forget cascades for face recognition (but they are  useful finding a face to recognize by some other algorithm). If your face database is not too huge, try SRC http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/recognition/Files/PAMI-Face.pdf. It gets good results and is not hard to implement. Even using PCA to learn subspaces for each face, then choosing the closest subspace for your test face can get good results  (e.g. Eigenfaces)

Comment: As @berak pointed out, You can't use cascades for face recognition. Use instead the OpenCV face recognition functions. In any case, for face databases, you can check out this page: http://www.face-rec.org/databases/